# wso2esb - aggregate mediator is not being detected

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 4.0.3 on Mac OSX 10.6 I have Data Services Server feature enabled(3.2.2

working in wso2esb 4.0.3 on aggregate mediator.

Below is the code, where the iterate mediator worked perfectly, but the aggregate mediator does not seem to get recognized, as the log in it is not getting printed .The response from the endpoint is getting printed in the log level=full of outsequence, but the flow is not getting continued in aggregate.

Could anyone from wso2team please confirm whether aggregate behaves as expected in wso2 esb 4.0.3?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" statistics="enable">
<target>
    <inSequence >
        <log level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="InSequence-EntryMessage" value="test - Entering InSequence."/>
        </log>
        <iterate preservePayload="true" attachPath="//REQ" expression="//REQ/MODULE">
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <payloadFactory>
                        <format>
                            <MODULE>
                                <party_id>$1</party_id>
                            </MODULE>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg expression="//REQ/MODULE/party_id"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <log level="full" separator=",">
                        <property name="InSequence-iterate" value="formed after iterate"/>
                    </log>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint key="conf:/test/ds_endpoint.xml"/>
                    </send>
                </sequence>
            </target>
        </iterate>
        <log level="custom" separator=",">
            <property name="InSequence-ExitMessage" value="test - Exiting InSequence."/>
        </log>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence >
        <log level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="ValidResponse" value="test  Sending the Response Back."/>
        </log>
        <aggregate>
            <log level="full" separator=",">
                <property name="ValidResponse" value="TEST ---------------- Sending the Response Back."/>
            </log>
            <correlateOn expression="//TEST"/>
            <completeCondition> 
                <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/> 
            </completeCondition> 
            <onComplete expression="//TESTALL">
            <log level="full" separator=",">
                <property name="ValidResponse" value="TEST 1 ---------------- Sending the Response Back."/>
            </log>
            <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
        <log level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="OutSequence-ExitMessage" value="test - Exiting OutSequence."/>
        </log>
    </outSequence>
</target>
</proxy>
```

Appreciate a response on this!

Answer (score 2):

Log mediator is only applicable inside "onComplete" tag in Aggregate mediator. So following log will not recognized and it is an expected behavior,

```
<log level="full" separator=",">
   <property name="ValidResponse" value="TEST ---------------- Sending the Response Back."/>
  </log>
```

but the following log which you have added within "onComplete" tag should work,

```
<log level="full" separator=",">
<property name="ValidResponse" value="TEST 1 ---------------- Sending the Response Back."/>
</log>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I did not get to see the log onComplete as well. Output of endpoint is <TEST>....</TEST>, hence I had given correlate on expression on //TEST and later to merge the collected messages on using oncomplete expression <//TESTALL>. Now the final output should be like <TESTALL><TEST>...</TEST><TEST>...</TEST></TESTALL>, which I did not get to see, as well as the logs.Could you please correct me if I am wrong in correlating the messages to the final output?

Comment: I have also tried the below section, to see if aggregate and the log is working, but in vain. Could you please point out the mistake if any?
<aggregate><!--<correlateOn expression="//TEST"/>-->
<completeCondition>
<messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/>
</completeCondition>
<onComplete expression="//TEST">
<log level="full" separator=","><property name="ValidResponse" value="TQS_SMART_FRAUD ----------------3333 Sending the Response Back."/>
</log>
<send/>
</onComplete>
</aggregate>

Comment: You can't achieve this behavior with above configuration. Because you can't put the aggregated message in to <TESTALL> by defining "expression" parameter in onComplete tag. "expression" parameter in onComplete tag is an XPath expression specifying based on which elements to aggregate. So you dont need to use  "correlateOn" parameter here. In order to attach the aggregated message in to  <TESTALL> tag you need to add a payload factory or enrich mediator for that.

Comment: So your new configuration would look like this.                                                       <aggregate>
            <completeCondition> 
                <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/> 
            </completeCondition> 
            <onComplete expression="//TEST">
           <--use payload or enrich mediator to add <//TESTALL> ---->
            <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>

Comment: Your above configuration looks fine, doesn't it print the log?

Comment: Yes, this configuration that I had already tried, neither did it give me the desired output or printed the log.<aggregate><completeCondition> <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/></completeCondition> <onComplete expression="//TEST"> <log level="full" separator=","><property name="ValidResponse" value="TQS_SMART_FRAUD --- Sending the Response Back."/> </log><send/></onComplete></aggregate>.Now my output or the aggregated message should be <TEST>...</TEST><TEST>....</TEST>. Could you please confirm whether my code and output that I expect is correct?Alo whether ESB 4.0.3 supports aggregate mediator?

Comment: Yes, the code and expected output is correct. And ESB 4.0.3 supports aggregate mediator as well. Can you verify whether the response message has <TEST> element.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Yes ,The output from the endpoint has the xml result as <TEST>....</TEST>.